# Паттерн фабрика

Tags: php

Я не понимаю, как происходит это сравнение, если вызвать

```
$pizza = PizzaFactory::createPizza('Havai');
```

то выведет **Гавайская пицца**

Где это сравнение в коде, я вообще не понимаю.

```
<?php

abstract class PizzaType {
    public function getPizza(){}
}

class HavaiPizza extends PizzaType{
    public function getPizza(){
        echo 'Гавайская пицца';
    }
}

class SalamyPizza extends PizzaType{
    public function getPizza(){
        echo 'Салями пицца';
    }
}

class PizzaFactory
{
    public static function createPizza($name)
    {
        $className = $name.'Pizza';
        if(class_exists($className)){
            return new $className;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}

$pizza = PizzaFactory::createPizza('Havai');
if($pizza){
    print_r($pizza->getPizza());
}else{
    echo 'Такой пиццы нету!';
}
```

Comment: если убрать 1 символ Hava, то будет Такой пиццы нету

Comment: я кажись начинаю понимать, в $className = $name.'Pizza'; попадает Havai и получается HavaiPizza и создаётся объект HavaiPizza

Comment: `$className = $name.'Pizza';
        if(class_exists($className)){
            return new $className;` - вот же русским языком написано

Comment: $className = $name.'Pizza'; = HavaiPizza, дальше проверка на такой класс - а он есть.

Comment: А этот класс ищется в корне файла? в мануале не написано

Comment: Класс ищется среди известных классов во файлах PHP которые были загружены через include, include_once, require, require_once
А также самый первый скрипт, который был вызван через web или через консоль
Порядок загрузки файлов PHP не важен

Если класс не определён, то ядро PHP пытается найти способ определить файл, который бы нужно подгрузить в память, для этого используются авто-загрузчики
см. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Если в разных файлах (нечаянно или специально) будет определение класса с одинаковым именем - будет фатальная ошибка, прекращение работы скрипта

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот ваш код, с которого начинается выполнение вашего скрипта. Обратите внимание на мои комментарии в нем:

```
$pizza = PizzaFactory::createPizza('Havai'); // Первая часть кода
if($pizza){
    print_r($pizza->getPizza()); // Вторая часть кода
}else{
    echo 'Такой пиццы нету!';
}
```

А теперь посмотрим, что происходит (опять же, смотрите комментарии). Первая часть кода:

```
class PizzaFactory
{
    public static function createPizza($name)
    {
        // получаем HavaiPizza
        $className = $name.'Pizza';
        // проверяем, есть ли в текущей области видимости класс HavaiPizza
        if(class_exists($className)){
            // если класс есть, а он есть, создаем новый экз. этого класса
            return new $className;
        }else{
            // если класса нет, вернем ложь, это пригодится во второй части кода
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

*Ремарка: функция `class_exists` проверяет по всей текущей области видимости скрипта, объявлен ли такой класс где-либо в текущем файле или же в подключенных тем или иным образом. У вас все просто - данный класс объявлен прямо в вашем же скрипте.*

Далее, после создания нового экз. нужного вам класса, у вас выполняется вторая часть кода, перед которой есть проверка, что нам вернул метод `createPizza()`, ложь или некий объект. Так как выше мы убедились, что объект нам вернется, то выполнится `print_r($pizza->getPizza())` в том коде, который я дал первым в своем ответе, который в свою очередь сделает вот это:

```
class HavaiPizza extends PizzaType{
    public function getPizza(){
        echo 'Гавайская пицца';
    }
}
```

Вроде бы все очевидно.